# How to add Hyperlink to ASP .NET GridView control cells dynamically at run time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, aspxgridview

[image Grideview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVt88.jpg) I want to add an hyperlink to the particular column on run time dynamically. i was able to bind Data to gridview but tried few scenario adding link to the GridView:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = GetData(sGridName, 0, 0);
        Session["ColumnNames"] = "";
        columnNamesAll.Clear();//Empty the list of columns so as not to duplicate or exceed limits
        if (this.sGroupID != "RSST") { gvAllTableView.Columns.Clear(); }
        
        //Loop through the dataset and add Bound Fields to Grid View
        foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {              
            BoundField column = new BoundField();
            sName = dc.ColumnName.ToString();
            columnNamesAll.Add(sName);
            column.DataField = sName;
            if (sName == "ECD")
            {
                column.DataFormatString = "{0:M/dd/yy}";
            }
            column.SortExpression = sName;
            column.ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
            if (this.sGroupID != "RSST") { gvAllTableView.Columns.Add(column); }
        }

        Session["ColumnNames"] = columnNamesAll;


//'set the properties of the GridView Control
        gvAllTableView.AllowSorting = true;
        gvAllTableView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gvAllTableView.AllowPaging = true;
        //APLN hyperlink
        gvAllTableView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        gvAllTableView.SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(Session["Selectedindex"].ToString());
        gvAllTableView.DataBind();
```

After binding data, this is the gridview looks like: [image]

Now i want to add Hyperlink only the ECD column. [Note: ECD may come in any order].

Comment: I believe you're looking for [Template Field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24457326/22083798) - there you can write ItemTemplate with a Hyperlink for specific column

Comment: Similar question with the answer, you can look to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193077/add-hyperlink-dynamically-to-gridview#:~:text=Correct%20way%20to%20do%20is,is%20bound%20to%20the%20gridview.&text=Please%20note%20since%20I%20have,Row.

Comment: @nafrolov, i wanted add HyperlinkField, and once i click on the column data it must take me to the URI which i give.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/143724/how-to-add-Hyperlink-in-gridview-in-ASP-NET